# Can we make layout from css using flex or block css property?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Its auto generated `HTML` from `CMS` and item will dynamic inside of `ul`. But i need layout like

[image]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-pro li {
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pro">
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-pro">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-pro">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-pro">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can i achieve layout like this. Is it possible to make from css using `flexbox` or `float` or `block` or not?

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add or adjust, for you to accept?

Comment: yea its working ok
I will accept this one.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve that without a markup change by simply display all the inner most `ul` and the outer most `li` as inline elements.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pro > li, .sub-pro {
  display: inline;                 /*  added  */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sub-pro li {
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pro">
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-pro">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2a</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2a</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2a</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-pro">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2b</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2b</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sub-pro">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2c</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2c</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Task 2c</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.sub-pro li {
  padding: 0 10px 10px;
 float :left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

[refer](https://jsfiddle.net/)
just make these changes , if any queries let me know

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this also.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
 width: 700px;
 background-color: pink;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  
}

.pro li {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="pro">
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
    
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Task 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you miss _Its auto generated HTML from CMS..._, which mean you have to use the existing markup, and with that this won't work